# How to show a div if a checkbox is checked on an edit page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am making an editing page for my users, that let them edit them info, but i can't understand why my code don't work ...

```
<div > 
 <input type="checkbox" name="Example" <?php if($Example=='1') {echo'checked';}?> value="1" onload="Check()" onclick="Check()"  class="Check"/> Some text <br>
 </div>

<div class="input" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="abc" class="input" > Som e text <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function Check() {
                var checkbox=document.getElementsByClassName('Check')[0];
                var example=document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0];
                if(checkbox.checked){
                    example.style.display='block';
                }else{
                    example.style.display='none';
                }
            }
</script>
```

I want  show the input field not only when the user click on the checkbox, but also when the user have as $Example, the value of 1. (The value of $Example is a value that the user inserted in the database at the registration time, and this value could be 1 or 0) I get no error!
Thanks for read, hope that you 'll have anice day!

Comment: what are you getting when page is shown and also describe what you want so that we can resolve according to your requirement.

Comment: @Deepansh Sachdeva  Updated!

Comment: glad to know. Please provide the answer also that how you fixed it. It may help others on the same issue in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the Check() function initially to make sure the correct state is set before the user interacts with the form - otherwise this only happens after the user changes the state.

```html
<div > 
 <input type="checkbox" name="Example" checked onload="Check()" onclick="Check()"  class="Check"/> Some text <br>
 </div>

<div class="input" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="abc" class="input" > Som e text <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            Check();  //make sure we set the correct initial state

            function Check() {
                var checkbox=document.getElementsByClassName('Check')[0];
                var example=document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0];
                if(checkbox.checked){
                    example.style.display='block';
                }else{
                    example.style.display='none';
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: I want  show the input field not only when the user click on the checkbox, but also when the user have as $Example, the value of 1. (The value of $Example is a value that the user inserted in the database at the registration time, and this value could be 1 or 0)

Comment: Aha, you didn't explain that! Edited my answer to fix the problem.

Comment: wow thanks a lot, can you please example me what do the Check()? Anyway thank you for support!!